cdk python - given that I need to give a role, how do I specify the resource?
self.fargate_execution_role = iam.Role(
                self,
                "GitlabExecutionRole",
                assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"),
                managed_policies=[
                    iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
                        "service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
                    )
                ],
                inline_policies=self.fargate_execution_role_policies
            )

How can I specify a resource, bearing in mind the above creates resource: "*"?
For example, I want it to be confined to accountid:resource, of which there may be many. For example cloud watch and ecs.
Many thanks

If you use the L2 constructs for creating a Fargate service, the execution role is created automatically and has its resources appropriately scoped. You can also add policies to that role as needed. I'm not sure I understand the context in which you are needing to create this role manually.

You can limit IAM policy resource scope with inline policies and customer managed policies.  AWS managed policies obviously allow all resources.
An inline policy (CDK Policy) is part of the role.  A customer managed policy (CDK ManagedPolicy) exists as separate CloudFormation AWS::IAM::Policy resource.
That difference aside, these policies work the same.  They both are built up from IAM policy statement (CDK PolicyStatement) building blocks, that specify the who-what-when of the policy.  To limit actions to certain resources, pass the in-scope ARNs to the statement's resources prop: resources: ["my-arn"].  See Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Elastic Container Service in the IAM docs for a list of valid resource types by action.  Resource ARNs can have * wildards.
Pass the policies to the Role props, as in your question.  Or, add statements to the role instance afterwards with the add_managed_policy(policy) method or inline with add_to_policy(statement).

Thank you. Sounds like I need a customer managed policy.
